# Access user information across activities Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In one activity, I am signing in the user, and it moves on to another activity where the user is greeted. I am using the built-in Firebase methods for signing in a user using email/password. I have the UID in Firebase Database and this is linked with a name. I am just manually inputting users in Firebase and will implement a sign up activity later. How do I access the UID of the user in the second activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively to passing the uid around, you can [use an auth state listener to detect the user in each activity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). From that documentation page:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
        // ...
    }
};
```

This code would typically go into a base-class that you derive your activities from.

Comment: Would I need to add this in the sign-in class as well? I tried this in the greeting class, but it doesn't work. Does this get data from the stored Auth Token created by Firebase?

Comment: The authentication state is indeed persisted between activities.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen do you know where the session is persisted? sharedpreferences maybe? thanks

Comment: Never mind, it is stored in the shared preferences, just checked, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

just use

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

String UID = user.getUid();
```

It will automatically get user from previous acivity.

Comment: Are you sure your code won't re-request the server to get the same instance back?

Answer (score 0):

You should either save it in `SharedPreferences` and retrieve it in the second activity or pass it into the second Activity via the `Intent` object.

`SharedPreferences` is one of the simpler ways to store data persistently in the app. Data stored in `SharedPreferences` can be retrieved and modified from almost anywhere in the app. Data will survive phone restarts, and even an app uninstall, because it can be backed up by the system. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) is the official explanation. And [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) is a good tutorial.

Comment: Can you expand on the SharedPreferences part please?